# Wpf Binding Stringformat to show only first character

Tags: wpf, binding, textblock, string-formatting

Is there any way so that i can show only first character of a Bound string on a textblock..?

For eg;If i Bind 'Male', my textblock should only show 'M'.....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might use a value converter to return a string prefix:

```
class PrefixValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string s = value.ToString();
        int prefixLength;
        if (!int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out prefixLength) ||
            s.Length <= prefixLength)
        {
            return s;
        }
        return s.Substring(0, prefixLength);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    ...
    <local:PrefixValueConverter x:Key="PrefixValueConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
...{Binding Path=TheProperty, Converter={StaticResource PrefixValueConverter},
                              ConverterParameter=1}...
```

Comment: Instead of throwing `NotImplementedException` in ConvertBack, throw `NotSupportedException`. NIE is for code that is not yet implemented but will be soon. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410719/notimplementedexception-are-they-kidding-me

Comment: TBH, It was actually not implemented yet, taking your advice, it now is :)

Comment: Yes..thanks Aviad,Actually i was looking to avoid using a converter.But seems like there is no way around...thx

Comment: You will get ArgumentOutOfRangeException in case `s` is shorter than `prefixLength`. Your condition should be: `if (!int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out prefixLength) || s.Length <= prefixLength)`