# Substring a bound String

Tags: c#, wpf, string, binding, string-formatting

What I want is to bind a string to a textblock or datatrigger (basically some WPF object) and take a part of the string. This string will be delimited. So, for example, I have this string:

```
String values = "value1|value2";
```

And I have two controls - `txtBlock1` and `txtBlock2`.

In txtBlock1 I would like to set the Text property like `Text={Binding values}`.
In txtBlock2 I would like to set the Text property like `Text={Binding values}`.

Obviously this will display the same string so I need some sort of StringFormat expression to add to this binding to substring values so that `txtBlock1` reads value1 and `txtBlock2` reads value2.

I've had a good read about and it seems like this: [Wpf Binding Stringformat to show only first character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006111/wpf-binding-stringformat-to-show-only-first-character) is the typical proposed solution. But it seems awfully long-winded for what I'm trying to achieve here.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a converter.
Add a converter parameter to indicate the index.

```
public class DelimiterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string[] values = ((string)value).Split("|");
        int index = int.Parse((string)parameter);
        return values[index];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "";
    }
```

Then you just specify the index of the value in XAML with the ConverterParameter attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a value converter as explained in the example your linked.

But if you want something that is more straightforward, you could use the following property and bindings:

```
public string[] ValueArray
{
    get
    {
        return values.Split('|');
    }
}

<TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueArray[0]}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueArray[1]}" />
```

But take care of what could happen if `values` is either null or doesn't contain `|`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have two string you can simply do:

```
<TextBlock Text=Text={Binding value1}/>
<TextBlock Text=Text={Binding value2}/>
```

and

```
public string value1
{
   get{return values.Split('|')[0]}
   set{values = value + values.Remove(0, values.IndexOf('|')+1)}
}
public string value2 ....
public string values ...
```

In fact you can write a function for `set value` and `get value` for related index (extend above approach),But if you don't like this syntax, IMO what you referred is best option for you.

Comment: The textblock I'm binding the string to will be as part of a datatemplate for listbox items. So the string will differ for each item. Thanks a lot for your reply, I'm sure I can use your solution here somehow.