# How to read first 5 characters from string using StringFormat in Windows Phone XAML?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

Basically in my Windows Phone application, i used to display the Name in the List through Binding. In this case, i want to restrict the name to display only the first 5 set of characters to avoid the unnecessary wrapping.

In my view, We can achieve this using the `Converter` option while binding the Name to the TextBox. But is there any other option to achieve this through XAML itself using `StringFormat` option while binding. Could you please anyone help me on this ?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat=??}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
```

Comment: Looking at this article, makes me think something like `StringFormat=\{0,5\}` would do what you need, although I haven't tried. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthiasshapiro/archive/2012/12/11/complete-guide-to-windows-phone-stringformat-binding.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this option. But it displays minimum of 5 characters. If we have name Tom means, It comes with " Tom". So it did not helped me.

Comment: Oh, so `Name` contains first name *and* last name, and you want the full first name + the first 5 characters of the last name?

Comment: No. There is no FirstName and LastName, If we have name with more than 5 characters, I should display only first 5 characters using StringFormat. Sometimes the name contains more than 15 or 20 characters means it makes unnecessary wrapping so i want to restrict to 5.

Comment: Oh I see, so my example would have worked but you'd need a way to trim the beginning spaces if the name is less than 5 characters?

Comment: No. From your solution, if we have 10 characters it just displays all the characters. It did not do any SubString option to restrict only to 5.

Comment: I think that the use of a converter will be necessary. Similar questions point in that direction: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176221/substring-a-bound-string 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006111/wpf-binding-stringformat-to-show-only-first-character

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this without using converter ?. That's what my actual question ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `TextTrimming` property of a `TextBlock` and create a style which contains a `TextBlock` inside your `TextBox`, like so:

## Style 1

```
<!-- Trims text but shows all on-focus -->
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key='TrimmingStyle1'>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Border BorderThickness='1' Background='#ffefefef' BorderBrush='LightBlue'>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" TextTrimming="None" Margin='4,1' />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

## Style 2

```
<!-- Trims text always, non editable -->
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key='TrimmingStyle2'>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Border BorderThickness='1' Background='#ffefefef' BorderBrush='LightBlue'>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" TextTrimming="None" Margin='4,1' />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

## Usage

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TrimmingStyle1}" ... />
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TrimmingStyle2}" ... />
```

Be sure to **change the text bindings** to match your application data. Also note that the trimming depends on the *size* of your textbox.

Source: [Using a Style to Simulate TextTrimming on TextBox](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2012/04/19/using-a-style-to-simulate-texttrimming-on-textbox/)