# Show float value in string, with negative c#

Tags: c#, string, floating-point

I have a float value that I want to put into a label.Text.

The float can be positive or negative, I am not sure the best way to do so. I was looking at String.Format but I am not sure how to use it properly.

Comment: Can you give us an example case ?

Comment: The float is a GPS number, it can be positive or negative, and a variable length

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert float to string - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016689/convert-float-to-string-c-sharp)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Not quite, the values are a bit different this is a little more informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your variable is called value holding float value then you can use it like following.

```
Label.Text = value>0? String.Format("-{0}", value ):String.Format("{0}", value );
```

Here is working fiddle for testing and playing with `string.Format()` => [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d5vFaZ)

Comment: Okay, I did NOT know about fiddle, these is my new favorite website. I added information to a comment in my first post.

Comment: @Demonicpenguin How you wanted to see that float number in text?

Comment: @Demonicpenguin did you really want to display the float variable as a negative number always? Now that's confusing

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply convert the float to string using `ToString()`

```
textbox1.Text = myFloat.ToString();
```

And if you are more interested in `format` method simply go through [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Unless I'm missing something, OP simply stated they want to display a float value in a textbox. Jenish's answer will always display the value as negative.