# "Not Implemented" exception with Visual Studio 2010 code coverage test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, exception, code-coverage

I upgraded from VS2010 Professional to Premium in order to use the built-in code coverage testing facility.  To make sure I was using the testing tool properly, I went through a small example with C#, which worked fine and showed me what code in my little test had executed.  Then, I went through the same steps with the actual application to be tested, which is a C++ app, making sure to build with the /Profile linker switch.

I could run my application in the debugger, and it ran fine.  Trying to run the code coverage test, however, failed when exception HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL) was thrown, apparently by Visual Studio itself. (At least, the Label on the dialog's title bar says "Microsoft Visual Studio".)

While I appreciate the irony of Visual Studio throwing a ["not implemented" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410719/notimplementedexception-are-they-kidding-me), I can't imagine how I'd go about tracking this down.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug was fixed in [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691).  Download and install the patch to see if it fixes your issue.